# hide warning on removing the directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I need to hide the warning message that pops up when I try to delete the directory which contains files in a Visual Studio setup project. How do I do that?

Comment: Deleting the directory from the filesystem or from within VS?

Comment: From the "filesystem on target machine" window.

Comment: So you're referring to the "Do you want to reload the project" prompt?

Comment: @squillman no, I am talking about "Cannot delete folder. Folder might not be empty or it might include excluded files." message when you want to delete a directory that contains other files.